# Missing part of the RAM after I installed new Fedora?

Tags: memory, installation, fedora, gnome, kde

I have installed new version of Fedora (22) after I had some problems with hard disk. However, I can only see 3GB of RAM now. But actually I have 8GB. What can be a problem and how I can resolve it.
Second, I installed it with Gnome, but now I see I don't like it, can I easily to switch to KDE (installing KDE and uni uninstalling gnome)?

Thanks!

Comment: you have almost certianly installed a 32bit OS. install a x64 version of Fedora, and you should see all your ram.

Comment: Thanks Frank. Now I saw, after uname -m command I get i686, not  x86_64.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding your memory issue, have you checked whether your Fedora distro is a x32 or x64 version? This might explain why only 3GiB of your memory is indexed by your OS and not the whole amount...

Comment: This seems more like a comment then an answer, since it does not really answer the author's question, a good answer should not generate additional questions

Comment: @Ramhound
1. My answer differs from Frank's only through the fact that it ends in a question mark. Treat it as a guiding step, but, if you follow the logic, you'll most certainly realise that it follows the same path as Frank's.
2. Before you downvote my answer, you should really check your grammar and spelling.

Comment: Except Frank didn't submit his comment as an answer.  I see no grammatical mistakes in my comment, even if they do exist, I don't want to hear about them.  If you improve your answer, to address my concerns, I will reverse my vote.  I hope you take my feedback into consideration before you submit future answers though.